# SQL Updating Issues using PHP within WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

This program receives a parameter to set a field in the table to either a y or an n based on the parameter value being passed either on or off respectively which indicates a desire to receive an email reminder for their daily bible reading.

It worked fine the first time and inserted a record with an appropriate y into a null table. The update worked find when I manually changed the field data manually in MySQL to something other than a y ran it with the on value. It correctly updated the value back to y.

When I changed the parameter to off it replaced the record changing the field to n. All further updates have either left the data unchanged or replaced it with an n regardless of the parameter value although the values for the update / insert indicate the SQL has the y in the code.

If I cut and paste the SQL echo'd into the manual MySQl as native SQL it works correctly. This is driving me NUTS! Please help. I have numerous programs with far more difficult and extensive code and I can't seem to figure this out.

```
if ($option=="on")
{
    echo "Option set to on";
    $message="<br>Reminder emails will start being sent tomorrow.<br><br>";
    $mail_flag='y';
    goto check_user;
}

if ($option=="off")
{
    echo "Option set to off";
    $message="<br>Reminder emails will stop being sent tomorrow.<br><br>";
    $mail_flag='n';
    goto check_user;
}

echo "Invlaid email option set.<br>Please inform us of this problem using the 'contact us' menu option.<br>Thank you.";
goto end;

check_user:
$prm_user_log_in=$current_user->user_login;

$select_data="SELECT * FROM SHD_Users_Data WHERE SHD_user_login ='$prm_user_log_in'";
echo "<br>select data = ".$select_data;

$result_select = mysqli_query($con,$select_data);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result_select);

if ($rowcount == 0)
{
    goto insert_record;
}

// record exists update it

$update_data="UPDATE SHD_Users_Data SET SHD_reminder_email = '$mail_flag' WHERE   SHD_user_login = '$prm_user_log_in'";
echo "<br>Update data is below <br>".$update_data;

if (mysqli_query($con,$update_data))
{
    Echo $message;
}
else
{
    echo "<BR>User Update Failed Error = ".mysqli_error($con).
    "<br> Please inform us of this problem using the 'contact us' menu option. <br>Thank you.";
}
goto end;

insert_record:

$insert_data="INSERT INTO SHD_Users_Data (SHD_user_login, SHD_reminder_email) VALUES ('$prm_user_log_in', '$mail_flag')";

echo "<br>Insert data is below<br>".$insert_data;

if (mysqli_query($con,$insert_data))
{
    Echo $message;
}
else
{
    echo "<BR>Failed Insert Error = ".mysqli_error($con).
    "<br> Please inform us of this problem using the 'contact us' menu option. <br>Thank you.";
    goto end;
}

end:
mysqli_close($con);
```

Here's the echo outputs from the program.

```
Running set_email_reminder.snippet.php
Option set to on
select data = SELECT * FROM SHD_Users_Data WHERE SHD_user_login ='wmayhew@walnuthillcc.org'
Insert data is below
INSERT INTO SHD_Users_Data (SHD_user_login, SHD_reminder_email) VALUES ('wmayhew@walnuthillcc.org', 'y')
Reminder emails will start being sent tomorrow.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it this way:

```
if ($option=="on")   {
    echo "Option set to on";
    $message="<br>Reminder emails will start being sent tomorrow.<br><br>";
    $mail_flag='y';
}
if ($option=="off")   {
   echo "Option set to off";
   $message="<br>Reminder emails will stop being sent tomorrow.<br><br>";
   $mail_flag='n';
}

$prm_user_log_in=$current_user->user_login;
$sql = "replace into shd_users_data (SHD_user_login, SHD_reminder_email) values ('".$prm_user_log_in."', '".$mail_flag."')";

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
   Echo $message;
}
else {
   echo "<BR>User SQL Failed Error = ".mysqli_error($con).
        "<br> Please inform us of this problem using the 'contact us' menu option. <br>Thank you.";
}
```

To use this be sure that the table has primary key on SHD_user_login and SHD_reminder_email